# Using FILTER or IMPORTRANGE to bring in and filter data from another spreadsheet with a keyword instead of exact match

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to use the importrange formula to import data from "spreadsheetA" that contains "keyword" in columnD.

I can get importrange to work but I cannot figure out how to filter it so it will only import if a keyword is found in column d.

Comment: I think I know how to help you, can you create a demo sheet with some dummy data?

Answer (score 0):

You nest an import range to a query to meet your desired result:

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("key","Sheet1!A:C"),"Select * Where Col2 contains 'Keyword'")
```

Demo sheet for you:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xT3kK4XGNGuAkMxSN2OvYmCgHn_tMsbbd4OjtwnmHRI/edit#gid=0

If you get a REF error you need to give yourself or get permission from the owner to read data from that sheet.